# Clone and change classname +1 and name of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am trying to figure out how to clone this div so that the cloned version has product 2 as its class name as well as the input nams to have rate2 and notes2.

```
<div class="product1">   
    <input id="rate1" name="rate1" type="number">
    <input name="notes" type="text">
<div>
```

**Trying to append in here ******

```
<div class="sixteen columns" id="addproduct">
   <label><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add another product</label>
</div>
```

=================================================================================

I have a rough idea of how to clone it but thats as far as my knowledge goes. I have looked at other posts and can't see an easy way of doing it.

JQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addproduct").click(function(){
            $(".product1").clone().appendTo("body");
        });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would advise against using this pattern. Using indexes in classnames or ids quickly becomes a headache to maintain. Instead use a common class and traverse the DOM to find the required elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, updated (v3)

Try

html (added `1` to end of attribute `name` , i.e., substitute `notes1` for `notes`)

```
<input name="notes1" type="text" />
```

js (v3)

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#addproduct").on("click", function () {
        var clone = $("[class^=product]:last")
        .clone(false, false)[0].outerHTML.replace(/(\d)/g, function(a) {
          return parseInt(a) + 1
        });       
        $(clone).appendTo("body");
        // console.log($(clone).attr("class"));
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/z2nxe84e/

Comment: Thanks, I used this and just added a counter instead of the 2 so it would work for multiple.

Comment: The old version with the counter seems to work fine, after more than two product fields have been added they remain at notes2 etc even on 3rd 4th... 

**however it does change the value of drop down option by mistake**

Comment: `var clone = $('#product-1').clone(false)[0].outerHTML.replace(/1/g, counter);` The regular expression also changes the value of my product in the select menu, is there a way to change just the 1 within the label. 

<label>Active Ingredient 1</label> ?

Comment: @vinnie667 jsfiddle ?

Comment: @vinnie667 Not certain about what is being described above ? If possible, can create / fork jsfiddle (with comments?) to view ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try to keep a counter for sake of simplicity and increment it every time you add a new row (product). Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // the counter:
    var productID = 1;

    // the click handler:
    $("#addproduct").click(function() {

        // clone last added product:
        var nextProduct = $(".product" + productID).clone();

        // add corresponding classes (remove old first):
        nextProduct
          .removeClass('product' + productID)
          .addClass('product' + (++productID));

        // update id and name to the first input:
        nextProduct.find('input').eq(0).attr({
            id: 'rate' + productID,
            name: 'rate' + productID
        });

        // update name of the second input
        nextProduct.find('input').eq(1).attr('name', 'notes' + productID);

        // append to the body:
        $('body').append(nextProduct);
    });
});
```

This should do the job, although I'd recommend adding some identifiers to the two inputs (e.g. different class names, so you would avoid using the `.eq()` expression.

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/puluf/1/edit

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! that live demo really helps, combined with the other answers I think I can grasp it now

Answer (score 2):

Well I suggest you to use `product-1 ,product-2 and so on` as your ID and maybe `product` as your class name. By doing so, you can come up with something like this:

```
$("#addproduct").click(function(){
    var temp = $(".product").last().prop('id').split("-");
    $(".product").last().clone().appendTo("body");
    var result = parseInt(temp[1]) + 1;
    //assume this last product is the one that already added
    $(".product").last().prop("id", "product-"+result); 

});
```

Another way:

```
$("#addproduct").click(function(){
    var temp = $(".product").last().prop('id').split("-");
    var result = parseInt(temp[1]) + 1;
    var html = $(".product:nth-child(1)").html();
    $(".product").last().after('<div id="product-'+result+'" class="product">'+html+'</div>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement this as well as look up what each of the jquery functions do.